# DSE Backup failure after upgrade

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

Good morning,

We recently process to the upgrade of our DSE cluster, from 5.0.7 to 5.1.
We followed the upgrade procedure and everything seemed to be OK.

But since that upgrade, the backup of our keyspaces fails every time.
The detail says "Mismatch of keyspaces and/or tables in schema and those known to the agent".

We have the same error in the agent's log:

`WARN [Thread-407] 2017-07-17 10:12:33,534 Mismatch of keyspaces and/or tables in schema and those known to agent`

Config :

> OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / 4.4.0-66-generic
>
> dse-full         5.1.0
>
> datastax-agent   6.1.0
>
> opscenter        6.1.0

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are a DataStax customer, you could open a Support ticket to help triage this issue.

Comment: AFAIK members of the startup program don't have access to support tickets.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue when we upgraded from 4.8 to 5.0
Our OpsCenter version was 6.1.6

The solution was to restart OpsCenter. This was the suggestion from datastax support also